# Laravel stop chained jobs only if main job is failed

Tags: laravel

I have two different jobs, but the second job depends on first job.

I tried job chaining, but when first main job is failed, still the next job in chain gets executed.

```
RegisterCustomer::withChain([
      new UpdateCustomerInvestment($investment)
])->dispatch()->allOnQueue('banking');
```

the `UpdateCustomerInvestment` still runs, even if the first `RegisterCustomer` fails, I have used the try catch, so then i did throw exception again in catch so that job would know that it has been failed.

How to stop the chain if main job is failed?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801397/4881811) !

Comment: @Maraboc
Its another approach, but i do not have a need of sharing data between jobs.
Thou i want if first job fails, the second job should not be executed.
Isn't this Job Chaining should be doing by default?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#job-chaining), if one job in the sequence fails, the rest of the jobs will not be run. So you could maybe pull the logic in your `RegisterCustomer` job into a separate job, and then `RegisterCustomer` just kick-starts the chain.